# PEP8 error in import line: E501 line too long

Tags: python, coding-style, pep8

I have a python import string. PEP8 linter show to me E501 error `line too long (82 > 79 characters)`:

```
from tornado.options import define, options, parse_config_file, parse_command_line
```

Solution with two line seems weird to me:

```
from tornado.options import define, options, parse_config_file
from tornado.options import parse_command_line
```

How I can fix it without disable E501 for this line?

Comment: According to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id19): `For code maintained exclusively or primarily by a team that can reach agreement on this issue, it is okay to increase the nominal line length from 80 to 100 characters (effectively increasing the maximum length to 99 characters), provided that comments and docstrings are still wrapped at 72 characters.` - consider making it 100 (99 instead of 79).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) for your options. Parentheses are probably the way to go.

Answer (score 13):

Put your imported names in parentheses, letting you span multiple lines:

```
from tornado.options import (
    define,
    options,
    parse_config_file,
    parse_command_line,
)
```

Using one line per name has the added advantage that later edits to the list of names imported reduce line churn (you can see what was added and removed in your version control system as separate lines).

Answer (score 1):

You should write it the way you think is more readable.. the 80 column limit was put in place for old style terminals that did not support re-sizing, which itself was for legacy support of terminal only computers where the monitor was only 80 chars wide. See: [A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds) #1 from pep8